# Offline PCAP to Jmeter JMX

Tags: jmeter, pcap, converters

Dears,

Any Idea of an offline replacement to https://converter.blazemeter.com/  to convert a PCAP to JMeter JMX.

As the PCAP contains sensitive data that we can not upload online.

I need an inhouse tool

Thanks

Comment: No Ideas for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the following options:

1. You can use [`tcprewrite`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcprewrite) tool to replace the "sensitive" data with the dummy data in  your .pcap file and use the aforementioned converter. Once you get the .jmx file you can replace the dummy data back with the sensitive data
2. If you want fully offline solution you can consider using [`tcpreplay`](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/) application which can replay .pcap files via [JMeter Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server/) which will capture [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.
3. You can open the .pcap file via [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), copy raw TCP request data and put it to [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler.